# Can you chain properties with __set in PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to chain properties together in PHP?

I tried to get it working like with method calls, similar to this:

```
class DefClass
{
    private $_definitions = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_definitions[$name] = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}

$test = new DefClass();

$test
    ->foo = 'bar'
    ->here = 'there'
    ->goodbye = 'hello';
```

But it didn't work.  Is it only possible to return the object and access it again with a method call?

Answer (score 2):

That's not even proper syntax. Remember, [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) is not a normal function call (hence why it's refered to as [magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)). If you really want to do this, make it a true function and forgo the overloading

```
public function setVal($name, $value)
{
    $this->_definitions[$name] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

And then you can do

```
$class->setVal('foo', 'bar')->setVal('bob', 'baz');
```